# Cache Digests and Mongoid Touch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have some models where the parent models need the updated_at field touched for invalidating cache digests. Here are my basic (simplified) models:

```
    class Location
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps
        has_many :departments

        field :name, type: String
    end

    class Department
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps
        belongs_to :location, touch: true
        has_many :positions

        field :name, type: String
    end

    class Position
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps
        belongs_to :department, touch: true

        field :name, type: String
    end
```

If I create a new Position, the Department and Location ancestors are touched. Unfortunately, nothing happens if I update or delete a Position. I've seen references that touch needs to be called manually with something like:

```
    after_save :touch
    before_destroy :touch
```

What is the proper use in this situation? Do I need to use these callbacks when it has to fire up the hierarchy only? The documentation is unclear about how this is **supposed** to function. Can anybody clarify this for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem myself. Based on the after_save/before_save solution it seems you may have already come across this GitHub issue, but the gist of it is that the touch option is working as intended. That is to say it only fires when the child doc is created or destroyed (there's an odd case with destroying that isn't entirely covered as well).

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/2373